# How to get last children records with parent record from database

Tags: sql, database, linq-to-sql

I have database with two tables: 
`Customers (Id PK, LastName)` 
and 
`Orders (Id PK, CustomerId FK, ProductName, Price, etc.)`

I want to retrieve only customer' **last** orders details together with customer name.
I use .NET L2SQL but I think it's SQL question more than LINQ question so I post here SQL query I tried:

```
SELECT [t0].[LastName], (
    SELECT [t2].[ProductName]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t1].[ProductName]
        FROM [Orders] AS [t1]
        WHERE [t1].[CustomerId] = [t0].[Id]
        ORDER BY [t1].[Id] DESC
        ) AS [t2]
    ) AS [ProductName], (
    SELECT [t4].[Price]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t3].[Price]
        FROM [Orders] AS [t3]
        WHERE [t3].[CustomerId] = [t0].[Id]
        ORDER BY [t3].[Id] DESC
        ) AS [t4]
    ) AS [Price]
FROM [Customers] AS [t0]
```

Problem is that Orders has more columns (30) and with each column the query gets bigger and slower because I need to add next subqueries.

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `SQL Server 2005` and above:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  o.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY o.id DESC) rn
        FROM    customers c
        LEFT JOIN
                orders o
        ON      o.customerId = c.id
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

or this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    customers c
OUTER APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 *
        FROM    orders o
        WHERE   o.customerId = c.id
        ORDER BY
                o.id DESC
        ) o
```

In `SQL Server 2000`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    customers с
LEFT JOIN
        orders o
ON      o.id = 
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 id
        FROM    orders oi
        WHERE   oi.customerId = c.id
        ORDER BY
                oi.id DESC
        )
```

Comment: in SQL 2008: only 2nd one works, 1st: The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 'q'.

Comment: @jlp: try now. You should specify explicitly which columns you want in the inner query.